# bad operand types for binary operator '!=' first type: String second type: int

Tags: java, comparison

I have a problem concerning the display , I would like to see each items from my variable CodeA of type String which is in a JComboBox. The variable CodeA represents each identification from the table Album.

In my DaoAlbumMySql I have error message..

*bad operand types for binary operator '!='   first type:  String   second type: int*

The problem is according NetBeans the `if (idCat != 0)`

```
   public ArrayList <Album> selectAlbums (String idCat)
        {
            ArrayList <Album> myList = new ArrayList();
            String req;

            if (idCat != 0)
            {
                req = "Select CodeA, TitreA, A.IdentC, DenomCat, " +
                " DateArrivee from album A,  " +
                "chanteur C where A.IdentC = C.IdentC" +
                " and CodeA = " + idCat + " order by 1";

            }
```

Comment: `!idCat.equals("0");`?

Comment: `idCat != null`?

Comment: my problem is resolve thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems here:

1) You are trying to compare a String to an `int` (`0`). You need to put quotation marks around it to make it a `String` to `String` comparison.

2) You are comparing with `!=`. This is incorrect to compare Strings. Compare with the `.equals()` method when comparing `Strings`

(As it is you are checking for (With `!=`) reference comparison (address comparison) The `.equals()` method checks for content comparison.)

Answer (score 0):

Unsure what you really want do do. For the moment you compare an String to an Integer.

If idCat should not be **null** then you have to

```
if (idCat != null)
```

If it must not **null** nor **empty**

```
if ((idCat != null) && (!idCat.isEmpty())
```

or last if it should not contain the value "0"

```
if (!"0".equals(idCat))
```

Comment: mercy I have understand my problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Two comments:

1) You can't compare String with int in Java. I think you tried to detect a null value? Depending the version of Java you're using, you could use java.lang.Optional as an alternative to others provided answers

2) Try to use interface instead of implementation classes when it is possible... Here, you can replace a lot of ArrayList to List.

Regards